# poppler library for Android app (NDK) will be possible instead of xpdf?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, static-linking, poppler

I need to create an Android app that shows pdf files and I want to use `xpdf` or `poppler` library. This question is only about these 2 choices. I already know how to exploit `poppler-qt4` so I'd prefer to use it but I fear that compiling it with NDK will yield a huge binary. Is it right? Should I use `xpdf`?

The question is: "Will I have troubles if I create an Android app with calls to `poppler-qt4` methods?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official website](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/):

> Poppler is a PDF rendering library based on the xpdf-3.0 code base.

So I guess the differences might not be that huge.

Integrating popplar might be difficult though, since it does not provide a front-end for the android GUI system.

I'm not sure about xpdf, though.

**EDIT:**

> Will I have troubles if I create an Android app with calls to poppler-qt4 methods?

Since the two GUI systems differ pretty much and do not have much in common, yes, I guess this won't be an easy task.

Comment: What if my program uses just some of the Qt4 types and few functions? shouldn't the compiler be able to static link just what is used? I think just QImage class and some bridge code is needed for my program.